# Trying to understand proof that 3 non-collinear points determine a unique plane

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$Q,R,P$ are 3 non-collinear points. Plane $M = P + s(Q-P) + t(R-P)$. Let $C = Q-P$ and $D= R-P$. Let us grant that C and D are linearly independent. Let $M' = P + sA + tB$. Assume $M'$ has $P,Q,R$. $M_0 = sA + tB$, a plane through the origin. $M'$ contains a vector $X$ iff $M_0$ contains $X-P$. Thus, since $M'$ contains $Q,R$, then $M_0$ contains $C$ and $D$.

(Here is the part I don't understand.)
This shows that there is one and only one plane containing $O,C,D$ because $C$ and $D$ are linearly independent.

I assume $O$ is the origin. It doesn't say. But how does $C$ and $D$ being L.I. show that there can only be one plane through 3 non-collinear points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A plane can be represented as the linear span of two linearly independent vectors (if the vectors were linearly dependent, you'd just get a line). So if $C$ and $D$ are L.I. then $OC$ and $OD$ are L.I. and the linear span of $\{OC, OD\}$ is a plane. Let's call this plane $A$. If $B$ is another plane containing $C, D$, and $O$, then $B$ can also be represented as the linear span of $\{OC, OD\}$ and therefore $B=A$.